# Openlayers inside jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, openlayers

I want to use Openlayers inside jquery ui tabs but I get error: "size is null"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem. It's explained at [jquery tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#...my_slider.2C_Google_Map.2C_sIFR_etc._not_work_when_placed_in_a_hidden_.28inactive.29_tab.3F) and [problems-with-google-maps-api-v3-jquery-ui-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428178/problems-with-google-maps-api-v3-jquery-ui-tabs).

What I did: in my jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css (most recent is 1.8.2) find the line:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: none !important; }
```

and change it to:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { position: absolute;
        left: -10000px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

What's i have done :

```
// Get hidden tabs content
var $cache = $(".ui-tabs-hide");

// Make them visible
$cache.removeClass("ui-tabs-hide");

// Initialize your map here
...

// Re-hide the tabs content
$cache.addClass("ui-tabs-hide");
```