# Getting trouble with jQuery tabs in loading openlayers map

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, openlayers

I've four `jQuery tabs`, in second tab I'm showing `map` using the `openlayers library` then I'm getting following errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'clone' of null // onload error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'w' of null // getting  this error when zooming-in and out
```

I thought my code went wrong in initializing the `openlayers map object` or `somewhere`,but it was actually trouble with `jQuery tabs`. If I'm placing `map div` in first tab then its showing `map` as expected.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333932/openlayers-inside-jquery-ui-tabs) but not solved the issue when placing `map div` in second tab.

**Update Below Content:**

If I write `jQuery tabs` code after the `map object` creation then its working fine in `chrome` but map destructing in `firefox`.

How can we call initialize `jQuery tabs` after execution of a user defined function?

Comment: Perhaps this is related to the size of the div where the map is loaded, has it some preset size when the map is loaded ? Width and height must be greater than zero.

Comment: I've checked width and height,both values are greater than zero.Its trouble with `jQuery tabs`, I think `display:none` is adding to the `map div`.

Answer (score 1):

you can initialize you map when enter to `tab`.

create you tabs like this:

```
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
     activate: function(event ,ui){
          if(ui.newTab.index() == 1)// tab number start from 0
           {
                    init(); // map initial function
           }
     }
 });
```

and define `init()` like this:

```
var map; //global variable
function init()
{
    if(map) //for create only one map
    { 
        return false; // if map exists it return and do not create another map
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works the first time but when you click again on the tab it will create a second map, click again creates a third map and so on..