# How to add Google Maps in two tabs of jQuery application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tabs in my jQuery application. I want to use Google Maps in both the tabs. I added script and two `<div>` tags for each tab shown in code below.

**First Tab:**

```
<div class="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

**Second Tab:**

```
<div class="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

**Script for Google Maps:**

```
function initialize() 
    {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.6952727, 77.5195312);
            var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementByClassName("map_canvas"),myOptions);

    }


----------Style for Google Map
.map_canvas { height: 100% }
#notes{ height: 100%;width:100% ; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }  // Tab1 div tag ,contains the First tab map Div Tag
#accordionWrapper{ height: 100%;width:100% ; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }// Tab2 div tag, contains the First tab map Div Tag
```

The map is not displaying in the two tabs. What is the problem here?

Comment: to find out what the problem is Run it in Google Chrome, go to Tools -> JavaScript Console and tell us what the error is. You can use Firebug in Firefox or F12 in IE9 as alternative.

Comment: oh, looks like it's a common JQuery tab issue, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428178

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) getElementByClassName() returns a  live NodeList of found elements in the order they appear in the tree: you should iterate over that nodeList and create a new map for each element because i don't think gmaps API allows you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to iterate the elements with the `map_canvas` class and create a new `Map` instance for each one of them, otherwise it will not work.

And I guess you are using jQuery UI Tabs for this? If so, you'll most likely run into trouble when loading Google Maps into hidden/inactive tabs. As mentioned in the comments there already exist questions about this with accompanied answers that solves this problem.

Anyhow, do the following changes/additions to your code and you should be good to go!

**CSS**

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

    // Container for maps
    var maps = [],
        // Initial position
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.6952727, 77.5195312),
        // Options for Google Maps
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

    // Iterate the canvas elements and create a new map instance
    $(".map_canvas").each(function(){
        maps.push(new google.maps.Map(this, mapOptions));
    });

    // Trigger map resize on tab change
    $('#id-of-tabs-container').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
        google.maps.events.trigger(maps[ui.index], 'resize');
    });

});
```

Replace the temporary ids to the corresponding ids of your elements.