# How to fullscreen googlemaps with jqueryplugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

As you see on the below picture, the map only shows up in upper left corner, It is possible to drag it around on the whole screen, but it will jump back to that square and only be displayed there.

The plugin mentioned in Title: [SemiOfficial jquery plugin](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html)

So I'm wondering how I can fix this?

Below the picture You'll find my html, a list of plugins, and the js code.

[image: Map only shows upper left corner]

**HTML/JSP:** (Should be mentioned this is the 2nd .jsp in my app, so it should hopefully initialize in the pageinit method)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>Map</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <!-- Start of first page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="mapmode" name="mapmode">

            <div data-role="header" id="header" name="header">
                <p>Header</p>
            </div><!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" id="content" name="content">   
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:300px;height:350px"></div>

            </div><!-- /content -->
        </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**PLUGINS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=_MY_KEY__INSERT_HERE_&sensor=true">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/FileManager.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/LocalAction.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Menu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MenuLoader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PageHeader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Mapmode.js"></script>
```

**Mapmode.js:**

```
var mapdata = {
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(59.3327881, 18.064488100000062)
};

$(document).on("pageinit", "#mapmode", function(event) {
    initMapMode();
    document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height=$(window).height();
    document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.width=$(window).width();
    //Create the map then make 'displayDirections' request
    $('#map_canvas').gmap({
        'center' : mapdata.destination, 
        'mapTypeControl' : true, 
        'navigationControl' : true,
        'navigationControlOptions' : {
            'position':google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
        }
    })
    .bind('init', function() {
        $('.refresh').trigger('tap');        
    });
});

$('#mapmode').on("pageshow", function() {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh');
});

function initMapMode(){
    initPageHeader();
    initMapModeContent();
}

function initMapModeContent(){
}

function fadingMsg (locMsg) {
    $("<div class='ui-overlay-shadow ui-body-e ui-corner-all fading-msg'>" + locMsg + "</div>")
    .css({
        "display": "block", 
        "opacity": 0.9, 
        "top": $(window).scrollTop() + 100
    })
    .appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer )
    .delay( 2200 )
    .fadeOut( 1000, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}

// Request display of directions, requires jquery.ui.map.services.js
var toggleval = true; // used for test case: static locations
$('.refresh').live("tap", function() {
    // START: Tracking location with test lat/long coordinates
    // Toggle between two origins to test refresh, force new route to be calculated
    var position = {};
    if (toggleval) {
        toggleval = false;
        position = {
            coords: {
                latitude: 57.6969943, 
                longitude: 11.9865
            }
        }; // Gothenburg
    } else {
        toggleval = true;
        position = {
            coords: {
                latitude: 58.5365967, 
                longitude: 15.0373319
            }
        }; // Motala
    }
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('displayDirections', 
    {
        'origin' : new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude), 
        'destination' : mapdata.destination, 
        'travelMode' : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    },
    {
        'panel' : document.getElementById('dir_panel')
    },
    function (result, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            var center = result.routes[0].bounds.getCenter();
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'center', center);
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh');
        } else {
            alert('Unable to get route');
        }
    }); 
    // END: Tracking location with test lat/long coordinates
    $(this).removeClass($.mobile.activeBtnClass);
    return false;
});
```

**initpageheader function:**

```
function initPageHeader(){
    //TODO getdata with the id(page we are currently on).
    $("#header").html(function(index, originalMarkup) {
        return '<a data-theme="a" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconshadow="true" data-shadow="true" '+
        'data-corners="true" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all" href="#" '+
        'data-rel="back" data-role="button"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">'+
        '<img src="../images/back.png" alt="back" align="middle" vspace="2"></span></span></a>'+
        '<h1 aria-level="1" role="heading" class="ui-title">'+
        '<img src="../images/main_header.png" alt="logo" align="middle" vspace="2">'+
        '</h1><a data-theme="a" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconshadow="true" data-shadow="true"'+
        'data-corners="true" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all" '+
        'href="#first" data-role="button" data-inline="true"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">'+
        '<span class="ui-btn-text">'+
        '<img src="../images/home.png" alt="picture to take you to the first page" align="middle">'+
        '</span></span></a>';
    });
}
```

Comment: We also need the CSS. GoogleMap sometimes can act like that when some parents don't have a relative position. Can you provide a fiddle which has all the required plugins ?

Comment: Its almost standard jquerymobile css, but sure ill put up something :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qDe7s/ ...
I'm new to fiddle, so don't hang me if this isn't what you wanted :)

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428178/problems-with-google-maps-api-v3-jquery-ui-tabs) (second answer) might be relevant. I have had a similar problem before and it was because the containing element did not have it's width and height defined when maps initialized. Maybe something similar is happening here?

Comment: Created a jsfiddle for you that has the bog standard googlemaps, jquery, jquerymobile, and the jquerymobile css in it. Works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/asfR9/

Comment: @smilledge If you can tell me how to use it with jquery gmap plugin, i'd be realyl really happy :)

Comment: I didn't realise you were using gmap, it wasn't included in your code above. The above code is also missing the `initPageHeader();` function

Comment: Yeah sorry about that @Jeemusu, both is described and implemented in the Q as of now.

Comment: used to have the same problem but on my side turned out to be because of the slow connection eventually it opened did you give it time ?

Comment: @PatsyIssa Yes I have given it lots of time :-) and my connection is really fast, else thanks :)

Comment: Hmm, it's going to be hard to help you without setting this up in a local testing environment. Try applying the CSS i have in this http://jsfiddle.net/asfR9/1/ . Specifically the `#map_canvas`, `div.ui-content` and `mapmode` ​.

Comment: @Jeemusu danm, think I forgot to say that mapmode, the page, is in a separate jsp file. So need stuff initialized in pageinit event, but it doesn't work if I do that there :/ (have also tried without, no glory that way either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the container that is holding the google map.

#map_canvas { max-width: none; }

Answer (score 1):

try to refresh the frame of the map with api function

after this line

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh');
```

try this

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it, but you need to have map object.