# my google map not completely loaded

Tags: google-maps

I use google map whit dragable marker, but its not completely loaded and when i use inspect element it loaded!
when i use codes in another page it works, but in my website no.

what should i do?
please help me.
this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.693, 51.437);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  // Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

}

// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="mapCanvas" style="width:715px; height:400px;"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <b>Marker status:</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <b>Current position:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <b>Closest matching address:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with Google Maps API v3 + jQuery UI Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428178/problems-with-google-maps-api-v3-jquery-ui-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set at least height parameter to #mapCanvas. Otherwise it wont display you the map.
try:

```
<div id="mapCanvas" style="height:200px;"></div>
```

**Edit**

As it came out below in comments, issue was with CSS properties.

Comment: @user1778843 can't see it from you code. Replace your div element with mine and give it a try.

Comment: i told its not loaded completely.

Comment: @user1778843 define "not completely" and show us demo please.

Comment: its not my page but like this map:http://chichmart.co/en/component/djclassifieds/ad/toyota,27/,209.html?se_reg[0]=1&se_reg[1]=17

Comment: @user1778843 Seems like some CSS issue to me. try calling checkResize() method on map at the end of the document

Comment: i used checkResize(), but didn't answer.